# Adding padding/margin/background around <text > tag in SVG

Tags: html, svg, text, tags, margin

[image]

Trying to style 'text' tag in SVG. For e.g, Adding Padding/ Margin/ Border, Background around the text. But, able to add only background using filter.

I have tried to add the background color and Padding/ Margin around the text. But could not find a way to add Margin/ Padding around the text.

Adding the text tag inside the SVG as follows,

```
<defs>
   <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="textStyle">
      <feFlood height="40" floodColor="green" 
       floodOpacity="0.08"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
   </filter>
</defs>

<text filter="url(#textStyle)"
 x={xCoOrd}
 y={yCoOrd} 
 fill="red">
</text>
```

Expected text similar to the attachment.

Comment: you'd really need to calculate the text bounds using javascript then add a rect before the text element. Or use HTML text rather than SVG text.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank You. Actually i need the coordinates to place the element( this is placed in a chart). So using svg text here.